# KnockoutJs, third party templating library, JsRender

Tags: knockout.js, jsrender

Is Knockout compatible with the latest JsRender release in terms of getting it to work with the `template binding`?

//Daniel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knockout's templating is not currently compatible with jsRender.

I did experiment with a jsRender template engine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MvCjB/), if you are interested in trying it.

Comment: i tested this and it worked pretty well. though i still have a lot of testing to go :)

Comment: +1 for starting a template engine. Interesting to see where this goes.

Comment: Can the jsRender engine accept templateOptions, and if so, how do I render them?