# how to use template with knockout, knockout mapping and jsrender

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, jsrender

I'd like to use a jsRender template to render the `fullName`, which is just the `firstName + ' ' + lastName`.  Instead of rendering the template with the data, it just renders as `{{=firstName}} {{=lastName}}`.  How can I make this work?

Live example: http://jsbin.com/inijay/2/edit

JS:

```
var data = { "firstName": "Ian", "lastName": "Davis" };
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName" type="text" />
<input data-bind="value: lastName" type="text" />
<span data-bind="template: 'fullNameTemplate'"></span>
```

Template:

```
<script id="fullNameTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  {{=firstName}} {{=lastName}}
</script>
```

What the output looks like: [image: broken jsrender template output]

Comment: If you really need to use jsRender then take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077539/knockoutjs-third-party-templating-library-jsrender.  Sample of a template engine for jsRender that handles it properly: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MvCjB/

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install your own `templateEngine`. Here's the finished result: http://jsbin.com/inijay/3/edit

Here's the relevant code:

```
ko.jsrenderTemplateEngine = function () { };
ko.jsrenderTemplateEngine.prototype = ko.utils.extend(new ko.templateEngine(), {
    renderTemplateSource: function (templateSource, bindingContext, options) {
        // Precompile the wrapping div for templating
        var precompiled = templateSource['data']('precompiled');
        if (!precompiled) {
            precompiled = $('<div>', { text: templateSource.text() });
            templateSource['data']('precompiled', precompiled);
        }
        // Unwrap observables
        var unwrapped = ko.mapping.toJS(bindingContext.$data);
        // Render and parseHTMLFragment
        return ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(precompiled.render(unwrapped));
    }
});
ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.jsrenderTemplateEngine());
```

I also changed your jsrender template:

```
<script id="fullNameTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{:firstName}} {{:lastName}}
</script>
```

I cribbed the basic code design from here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_using_the_underscorejs_template_engine

On a side note, this solution doesn't seem to be all that fast because the optimal-ness of jsrender is *rendered* useless by having to unwrap the observables all the time. I believe it would be better to use Knockout's native templates instead.

Comment: how would you use Knockout's native templates for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using jQuery.tmpl: http://jsbin.com/inijay/5/edit Documentation says that by this point it would update to jsRender, but apparently not. Documentation here: knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html